How to use useFirebaseAuth inside Pinia Store?
I'm trying to use Firebase Authentication with VueFire inside a Pinia Store to keep my code clean and have app wide access to the user data, but when I try to access the Auth instance with const auth = useFirebaseAuth() my app throws this warning:
inject() can only be used inside setup() or functional components.
And when I try to run any of the Firebase Auth methods, let's say that signInWithEmailAndPassword I get this error:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'app') at signInWithEmailAndPassword
This is my UserStore.js:
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import router from '../router/index'
import { useFirebaseAuth } from 'vuefire'
import { signOut, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth'

const auth = useFirebaseAuth()

export const useUserStore = defineStore('UserStore', {
    state: () => {
        return {
            user: {},
            isLoggedIn: false,
            email: '',
            password: '',
            repassword: '',
            errorMessage: '',
        }
    },
    actions: {
        async register() {
            if (this.password === this.repassword) {
                await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, this.email, this.password)
                    .then((userCredential) => {
                        const user = userCredential.user
                        console.log(user)
                        router.push('/:placeName')
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        const errorCode = error.code
                        console.log(errorCode)
                        this.errorMessage = error.message
                        alert(this.errorMessage)
                    })
            } else {
                alert('Passwords must match')
            }
        },
        async login() {
            await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, this.email, this.password)
                .then((userCredential) => {
                    const user = userCredential.user
                    console.log(user)
                    router.push({ name: 'menu' })
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    const errorCode = error.code
                    console.log(errorCode)
                    this.errorMessage = error.message
                    alert(this.errorMessage)
                })
        },
        async signout() {
            await signOut(auth)
                .then(() => {
                    router.push({ name: 'login' })
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    const errorCode = error.code
                    console.log(errorCode)
                    this.errorMessage = error.message
                    alert(this.errorMessage)
                })
        }
    }
})

If I move const auth = useFirebaseAuth() inside the State everything works just fine but I'm not sure if that's the right way to do that.

Have you checked that one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65341326/8816585

The useFirebaseAuth instance is imported just like in that question's answer and this is already a Pinia Store so I don't know what else to do.
